# Placing an image at a fixed position on a background in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout

I have to develop the design as attached below.
For achieving it, I created 2 separate linear layouts and given them `layout_weight` of 1 so as to divide the screen vertically into 2 background colours.
For the image, I extracted it as vector, and placing it on the basis of Guideline.

The issue I am facing is, the image is not fixed at the location, and is moving up and down depending on the screen sizes. How can I make sure that the image remains fixed at the same position as shown in the design?

My code so far,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff5757">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#5ce1e6">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/train_svg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ev_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="262dp"
        android:maxHeight="225dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/train_svg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/train_svg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/train" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Design,
[image]

Comment: Where exactly you want to place the image??

Comment: @KishanMaurya As shown in the design screenshot, horizontally centered and vertically as shown in the screenshot

Comment: I think, guideline not required. We can centred image vertically & horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff5757" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#5ce1e6" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ev_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="262dp"
        android:maxHeight="225dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my design I don't want to center it vertically, in the design it is not vertically centered.

Comment: How much image height % you want above central vertical line. 
With my approach it is 50% above & below central vertical line.

Comment: I want the image to be around 40% above central line and 60% below

Answer (score 0):

You can design the image on programs such as Photoshop, illustrator, xd, or any other program. Save the image as SVG
Convert the image from SVG to xml .Go to ->drawable folder-> Click the right
button of the mouse ->Choose from the menu **New** Choose **victor asset**

[image: Convert the image from SVG to xml]

Choose the image to convert
This is the xml image code

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="428dp"
    android:height="925dp"
    android:viewportWidth="428"
    android:viewportHeight="925">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0h428v463h-428z"
      android:fillColor="#ff5757"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,462h428v463h-428z"
      android:fillColor="#5ce1e6"/>
</vector>
```

You can copy and paste this code into a drawable xml file
Choose from the list new **Drawable resource file** .

Set the image as background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/component_1___1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bias` attribute to give more weight to a particular constraint. You first vertically center the image and give `bias` to upper constraint. `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"` for 60% below central line.

**TIP**: If you are not planning to put views in `LinearLayout` you can simply replace it with `View`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff5757"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#5ce1e6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cooked_egg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Sample Output]